# how to add a custom field that is not present in database in graphene django

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

so my model looks like

```
class Abcd(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=False)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, default=False)
```

need to pass a dictionary at query time which is not a part of model, query is

```
query {
  allAbcd(Name: "XYZ") {
    edges {
      node {
        Data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How does one pass such a custom field with the query ?.

This custom field is required for other process purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Graphene uses Types to resolve nodes, which are not at all tied to the model, you can even define a Graphene Type which is not associated with any model. Anyway the usecase you're looking for is pretty simple. Let's say that we have a model name `User` per say, I'm assuming that this `Data` needs to be resolved by the Model's resolver.

```py
from graphene.relay import Node
from graphene import ObjectType, JSONField, String
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from app.models import User

class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        filter_fields = {'id': ['exact']}
        model = User

    custom_field = JSONField()
    hello_world = String()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_custom_field(root, info, **kwargs):
        return {'msg': 'That was easy!'} # or json.dumps perhaps? you get the idea

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_hello_world(root, info, **kwargs):
        return 'Hello, World!'


class Query(ObjectType):
    user = Node.Field(UserType)
    all_users = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ProjectType)
```

Comment: Use `custom_field = GenericScalar()` instead of `custom_field = JSONField()` and import `from graphene.types.generic import GenericScalar`

Answer (score 1):

Small example:

**Brand** model

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**BrandNode**

```
class BrandNode(DjangoObjectType):
    # extra field INT
    extra_field_real_id_plus_one = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_extra_field_real_id_plus_one(parent, info, **kwargs):
        value = parent.id + 1
        print(f'Real Id: {parent.id}')
        print(f'Id ++: {value}')
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        filter_fields = {
            'name': ['icontains', 'exact']
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

`extra_field_real_id_plus_one`  is the extra field. You can get any value from the original model, exactly from the `parent` parameter. You can calculate or format whatever you want and just you need to return the value.
You can get the extra field calculated value in queries, mutations, etc.